# What does the points stand for?

Tags: java, eclipse

When I write the constructor in Java like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class MultiOutputStream extends OutputStream{

    OutputStream[] oStream;

    public MultiOutputStream(OutputStream oStream) { 
        this.oStream = oStream;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int arg0) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Eclipse now says: **Type mismatch: cannot convert from OutputStream to OutputStream[]**. So Eclipse corrected my constructor like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class MultiOutputStream extends OutputStream{

    OutputStream[] oStream;

    public MultiOutputStream(OutputStream... oStream) {
        this.oStream = oStream;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int arg0) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

What does these points stand for?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The aim is to allow the developer to pass 1, 2  , 3... args without having to write explicitly matching constructors and without forcing you to accept a `Collection`.

Comment: What prior research did you do?

Comment: At least I didn't know how to google for these three periods.

Comment: If u don't want to use varargs u can write ur constructor like this - **public MultiOutputStream(OutputStream[] oStream) {this.oStream = oStream;}**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are called "varargs", see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html.

> The three periods after the final parameter's type indicate that the
>   final argument may be passed as an array or as a sequence of
>   arguments.

Comment: Thank you very much! Didn't know how to google these points. :)

Answer (score 3):

It's a syntaxic sugar called *varargs*.

```
public void method(int... varargs) { }
```

You can call this method using multiple argument, for example: `method(3, 14)`, but also `method(42)`.
It's a common way to deal with method with an indeterminate numbers of arguments, it's used for example in `String::format`.

The compiler will automatically gather the arguments into an array behind the hood. In this code, `varargs` is an array of `int`, and so you could easily loop over it.

```
public void method(int... varargs) { 
  for(int i=0; i < varargs.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Argument n°"+i+" is "+varargs[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These points are called `varargs`. You can read more about them [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).

To summarize, they are used in order to allow infinite amount of parameters of that type to a method. This allows for easier access and cleaner code. The `vararg` is like an array when you try to use it.